# Using IN Condition with large number of items

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, in-clause

I have local data with id's from an external database. I want to then select data from that external database using those id so I do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (:listofids)
```

However I've noticed (I'm not sure if it's a DB by DB setting or the type of DB or what) there can be a max number of values allowed in that IN statement. When possible of course I do `WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ...)` but sometimes with external data it's not possible.

**My questions:**

1. What are my options here besides what I am doing in the above?
2. Are the limitations of max items set at the DB level, the type of DB, what? Right now I am specifically concerned with an external RedShift DB but I looked at their docs and they don't mention a limit. Our local DB has a limit of 2100 but another one I use is 9999.  Also, once the list gets large it can get slow, so i'm looking for a performance boost as well.
3. Should I do `in () OR in () OR in()`. That doesn't seem too slick. Are all of these options viable?
4. I've read a bit about possibly using temp tables to do this but without any examples. How would I load data into a temp table to then join into the table I'm wanting to get the data from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are my options here besides what I am doing in the above?

They are limited - you could chain a LONG sequence of `OR id = X` calls but you may have SIGNIFICANT performance problems compared to `IN`.

The *best* option performance-wise is to join to a table (parameter, temporary, CTE, inline `UNION`, or static) on the server side.  However that's not always an option depending on how you're executing queries and what permissions you have.

Of course, you can also execute a separate query for each value, which would be easier to code but might have performance problems as well.

> Are the limitations of max items set at the DB level, the type of DB, what?

That is platform-specific so there's not a universal answer

> Should I do in () OR in () OR in(). That doesn't seem too slick. Are all of these options viable?

That is one option to add to the others above - you'd have to try it to see what the performance impact is.

> I've read a bit about possibly using temp tables to do this but without any examples. How would I load data into a temp table to then join into the table I'm wanting to get the data from?

That depends on the platform, your permissions, your API available, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. So when you say the max items is platform-specific, do you mean MSSQL will always be 2100 max, oracle will always be 9999, etc or something else?

Comment: possibly - or the max could depend on the overall size (in characters) of the query, or something else altogether.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple solution, that avoids temporary tables, is to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.* 
FROM 
    [table] t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 'id1' AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'id2'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'id3') i ON i.Id = t.Id;
```

it's obviously a little bit more work to create a sub-query using lots of UNIONs, but this effectively creates a temporary table that you can use without having to worry about materialising it.